# Two column/row Positioning of labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I am making a plot in ggplot2 where on the y axis I have the indices of groups and on the x axis some information. For readability I would like to make the labels bigger but then they start overlapping. Therefore I would like to put the labels into two columns as shown in the figure so they can be bigger. Is there a way to do this in ggplot? I tried vjust and hjust but they only seem to accept 1 argument applying to all labels.

Current labels: [image: Current Labeling]

Objective labeling: [image: Objective labeling]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is no obvious parameter responsible for that, at least AFAIK.

However, for your specific goal my first thought was to add some spaces to numeric labels.

```
avoid_overlap <- function(x) 
{
  ind <- seq_along(x) %% 2 == 0
  x[ind] <- paste0(x[ind], "     ")
  x
}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 10:35, labels = avoid_overlap(10:35)) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 32))
```

[image]

Play with grid lines (minor/major) via `theme` if the grid is too dense.